# nodejs mysql pool getConnection continously fails with "Queue limit reached" after some time

Tags: mysql, node.js

I do have some problems that my node app starts hanging once in a while with the mysql error message "queue limit reached".

I'm getting the mysql connection from a mysql pool. However the server is on low traffic, thus it isn't possible that there isn't any mysql connection available. Also the queue length of mysql pool is set to 200 and the timeout to 500ms, thus this queue limit should never be reached. More likely the connection is to timeout.

mysql connections are closed/returned probably.

As soon as this happens every connection ends with this message, and it seems that the server isn't catching up with this at any time.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've had this issue before. I would personally recommend double checking (yes, I know) all your `getConnection` files to make sure that you are indeed closing them all. You may have missed one or two. Don't forget to check for exceptions and errors that could lead to an unclosed connection.

Comment: Check if you are not forgetting anywhere in your code to release the connections you ask for

Comment: seems probably closed. Is it possible to close any left over connection on req end / req close?